# Python Meta Programming

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I'm currently working on a rather big API project written in Python.
I have a couple of endpoints, in each of which I want to perform more or less the same snippet of code. However, I don't want to copy paste it, and it is rather complicated to put it into an extra function as there are always a couple of context variables like loggers or requests. Is there some sort of meta programming mechanism in Python, that lets me "expand" / dynamically "write" code on runtime / interpretation time? I'm used to this from closure, so maybe some of you know what I'm talking about.

Here is an example:

```
# code I want in each function that uses x, y and local logger


def f(x, y):
  # reference to the above code

  # actual code of f

def g(x, y, z):
  # reference to the above code

  # actual code of g
```

I tried to use a decorator, but that does not seem clean to me, and it interferes with other decorators, if used like I did.

As a note, I'm writing purely sequential / functional code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bit too general to answer, but usually decorators are the way. You do have `ast` for modifying code dynamically but that's not the general way of doing things in Python

Comment: Are you using some kind of web framework?

Comment: I'm using FastAPI, however, the problem occurred to me a couple times already and I'd like to learn how to solve it in a general way.

Comment: There is a concept in FastAPI of middleware if you wish to run code on every request https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/?

Comment: The midleware seems promising, I'll take a look at that thank you! Do you know any more general way in python, or is it usually just decorators?

Comment: Sorry for not clearly stating it, I'm looking for a more general way that helps me with this problem on future tasks not related to FastAPI:)